# Web Sphere Application Server v7.0

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

What are the different "wsadmin objects" are there in WebSphereApplicationServer, and what is the use of them?

Answer (score 3):

The AdminConfig, AdminControl, AdminTask, and AdminApp objects are described [here in the WebSphere documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=wsadmin-using-scripting-objects).

> - Use the AdminConfig object, the AdminTask object, and the AdminApp object to handle configuration functionality.
>
>   The AdminConfig object, the AdminTask object, and the AdminApp object are used when you are managing the configuration of the server
>   that resides persistently in a repository on permanent storage. Use
>   these objects to create, query, change, or remove this configuration
>   without starting an application server process. To use the AdminTask
>   object, you must be connected to a running server.
> - Use the AdminControl object to manage running objects on application server installations.
>
>   The AdminControl object is used when managing the running instance of an application server by a Java™ Management Extensions (JMX) MBean.
>   This instance can have attributes that you can interrogate and change,
>   and operations that you can invoke. These operational actions that are
>   taken against a running application server do not have an effect on
>   the persistent configuration of the server. The attributes that
>   support manipulation from an MBean differ from the attributes that the
>   corresponding configuration supports. The configuration can include
>   many attributes that you cannot query or set from the running object.
>   The application server scripting support provides functions to locate
>   configuration objects and running objects. The objects in the
>   configuration do not always represent objects that are currently
>   running. The AdminControl object manages running objects.

Comment: Link is corrupts and you check again please